# call oracle Procedure from Java In/out Paramaters

Tags: java, oracle, procedure

I should call a procedure from Java

```
 PROCEDURE getArray (           result            OUT INTEGER, 
                                code              IN CODE%TYPE,
                                type              IN TYPEELEMENT%TYPE, 
                                array             OUT ARRAY_T, 
                                state             IN INTEGER DEFAULT NULL);
```

ARRAY_T is `create or replace TYPE ARRAY_T IS TABLE OF ARRAY_T_ELEMENT;`

```
create or replace TYPE ARRAY_T_ELEMENTIS OBJECT
(
  ELEMENT_FATHER VARCHAR2(64),
  TYPE_ELEMENT VARCHAR2(10),
  DATE_BEGIN DATE,
  COD_ERR VARCHAR2(10)
);
```

My java code is

```
  stmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER);
        stmt.setString(2, code);
        stmt.setString(3, elementType);
        stmt.registerOutParameter(4, Types.ARRAY,"ARRAY_T" );
        stmt.setInt(5,1);
```

The error that comes out is **Conflict parameter type**.

I do not understand where I'm wrong and also I would like to know how to do nothing to pass for the last value since i would use the defualt in this case.

Thanks a lot

Comment: How defined CODE%TYPE and TYPEELEMENT%TYPE? Is it strings (char, varchar)?

Comment: Type is a varChar